# How to resolve this problem (access to invisibles folders) when using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

For example:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set fNo to folder "usr" of (path to startup disk) -- don't work
    set fYes to folder "Library" of (path to home folder) -- works
end tell
```

gives

**error "Erreur dans Finder : Il est impossible d’obtenir      folder "usr" of startup disk." number -1728 from folder "usr" of startup disk**

(***error in Finder: unable to obtain folder "usr" of startup disk." number -1728 from folder "usr" of startup disk***)

Setting `fYes` works probably because a gain access to my user Home in a previous attempt, but I forgot where/how.

So how can I grant the required access rights to the script?

Comment: Are you running the script from Script Editor?

Comment: @nohillside Yes.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for editing my question in a better way (I'm not a English speaker).

Comment: Perhaps the closing voter can reevaluate his vote? Sorry for the mistakes, it's  only by trial and error that one becomes more correct, I cannot be perfect in phrasing my problem in the first shoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn’t about Ventura, or security, but *visibility*.  Scripts using the **Finder** don’t normally see invisible items, the same way they are not normally shown in Finder Windows.  For an example, your sample script works (or not) when using the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>period</kbd> shortcut to toggle showing invisible items.  An alternative would be to use **System Events**.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The folder "Library" is hidden by default, but accessible (no error with `fYes` in my code). Can you elaborate about Command-Shift-Period ? Where is it used to toggle showing invisible items? Also, if I use Finder's Go menu and choose "Aller au dossier..." ("Go to folder..." probably) and enter "/usr", I see the "usr" folder and it's content in the Finder Window. About "System Events", does I use `tell "System Events"` in place of `tell "Finder"`? I can effectively use `set fNo to...`but after, in my script, i use `select fNo` and this isn't understood by "System Events".

Comment: And yes, I call `select fNo` in a `tell "Finder"` statement. But I have: **Erreur dans System Events :  folder "Macintosh HD:usr" ne comprend pas le message « select »** (Error in System Events: folder "Macintosh HD:usr" doesn't understand the "select" message).

Comment: @quark67 - Your original question doesn’t mention anything about the usage of a `select` command, but note that you can’t expect the same or similar terms to work the same in different applications.  The keyboard shortcut can be used when the Finder is active.

Comment: Can you edit you answer with a source who explain that "scripts using the **Finder** don't normally see invisible items. Thanks (Again, `Library` is invisible, but no problem, so this is strange...). I don't need to see the invisibles items, I use the script to restore items in the Finder sidebars after they randomly disappear (so I need the "select" command, then with `keystroke "t" using {command down, control down}` I can send items to the Finder sidebar (French shortcut ≠ US shortcut). Some items are folders in Home, others are folder in `\usr`.

Comment: @quark67 - The source would be from running your posted sample with invisible files not shown, then running it again after invisibles are shown.  You would need to ask Apple why it treats various items such as the user’s Library folder differently.  Can you edit your question to include _exactly_ what you are trying to do?  I was just answering the question that was asked.

Comment: Very useful hint, effectively "/usr" is invisible (grayed in Finder window) and don't work, but "/System/DriverKit" isn't grayed, and gives no error. My assumption was so false. So the answer is "grayed items in Finder windows cannot be acceded by "set fName to folder of .... of folder of .... of (path to startup disk)".

Comment: Finally I found a pure AppleScript method, see my answer. Thanks anyway for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

As the user **red_menace** pointed out, the folder I tried to access has a particularity: it is "invisible" (grayed out in Finder when acceded and displayed via Go > Go to Folder... menu item; type "/usr" in recent macOS to access to it).

I tried to access to it via AppleScript by the "folder ... of folder ..." command and this failed.

**But** there is another method to specify a folder  in AppleScript. And with this another method, all runs smoothly without fail.

Here is the method which works (perhaps others too).

```
tell app "Finder"
    activate
    set fNo to alias "Macintosh HD:usr"
end tell
```

I discovered this by testing the setting "fNo" to the folder with the AppleScript "set fNo to choose folder" (and in the choosing window, enter command+shift+G, and then type "/usr" in the prompt). And then I discovered  that in the Result part of the Script Editor window, fNo was in fact `alias "Macintosh HD:usr"`, so I tried directly this successfully.

Comment: Interesting.  Probably a "feature" of using a full path vs trying to find an invisible folder of a path.